# Dll not registering for all users

Tags: dll

Hopefully this is placed in the right area, but I seem to be having an issue with a registered dll.

Our main application is written with Power Builder Version 11, and through various objects, we are able to call registered C# .dll's

The C# .dll is created in Visual Studio 2008 and is installed via an installer that someone else in the building made. When a user runs the installer, they are given the option to register it for everyone or 'Just Me'

The .dll is installed successfully and the user that did the install is able to run the Power Builder application and call the functions inside the .dll.

The issue that arises is that any other user that runs the Power Builder application is greeted with a message box that says: Unable to connect to: [my dll].

I tried to re-register the .dll (using Regasm) but that doesn't work. I have confirmed that the folder is in the PATH System Variable.

The only solution I found was to uninstall the .dll from the Control Panel and re-install it from scratch. But, the same issue arise after the install.

What could the issue be? I'm starting to think that it has to be a rights issue but I can't be 100% positive.

Comment: What command did you use when you registered the dll manually? Note that you must use regasm.exe and not regsvr32 when registering managed COM components.

Comment: I used Regasm.exe. My fault, I should have said that in the initial question.

Comment: So how does regasm not work? Does it tell you an error message?

Comment: It says that the .dll is successfully registered, but when I run the Power Builder application it still says it cannot find the dll

Comment: Are you on a 64-bit machine? You should make sure to use the correct version (x86 vs x64) of regasm.exe then. They are located under `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\<version>` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>` respectively.